# I used multibit years ago - now what? (BTC, BTG, BCC etc...)

Tags: multibit, blockchain-fork, paper-wallet

I have some old wallets from multibit era (~2013).  There is no way I can now download the full blockchain, so I need to import these keys into somewhere.  Worse still, I also need to import the same keys for BCC and BTG.

Try as I might, I can't seem to find clients that allow me to import old base58 keys.  I have a few files called `something.key` which came from multibit and are human readable with the private key in.  Everything seems to be "mobile" and "QR codes", "passphrases" and whatnot.

It's not a lot of money, and fragmented over multiple wallets, so with transaction costs stupidly high now, sweeping is infeasible.

How can I spend these old coins?  Is the only way to free up 150GB and wait?

---

Edit:  Ultimately I just want to create a transaction from all these wallets, to send the coins to an exchange.  So sweeping to a new wallet just doubles all my transaction costs for no reason.  Also I need a way to repeat the process for Bitcoin Cash and Gold...

Is there no simple tool to just "create" a transaction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I sell my BTC and still claim my BCH?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/64691/can-i-sell-my-btc-and-still-claim-my-bch)

Comment: Your ultimate desire I don't think exists. I did this exact thing a month ago. The fees sucked a lot, but it is what it is.

Comment: @fredsbend well at the very least i know a can do an import if i run a full node of each coin, so I'd rather do that for btc than pay the fee!

Comment: How big a transaction are we talking here? BTG and BCH are negligible. BTC is really only bad if it's a small amount with tons of inputs. Then, how much time will it take you to set up a full node for each? All to save $50? My fees were about $170, but it was still worth it to me.

Comment: @fredsbend yeah i would only do it fot btc. Its only about 0.05 Btc but over a handful of different addresses so it will soon add up. And it's the principle dammit! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that worked for me:

BTC
Blockchain.info have online wallets but you can also just create your own transactions without using their wallet.  Add an address using import and then spend them directly using your private key.  You can manually set the fee and i managed to transfer with ~75sat/byte even though recommended was 225.

BCC/BTG
Transaction costs are still small for these so sweeping works fine using practically any wallet.