# senting wrong address from BCH to BTC address PLEASE HELP!

Tags: cross-chain-recovery

please help me I am New to this please show me step by step how to recover the lost coin let me explain.
First I used Trezor wallet sent bitcoin(BTC) out convert to bitcoin cash(BCH) using shapeshift.io, however the received address I input BTC received address instead of BCH address so I email shapeshift and asking to recovery my lost coin, they emailed me and say they're nolonger access to my coin to recover it, so they sent me a LINK (https://blockdozer.cominsight.tx.......) ask me to extract the coin using your private key...
please show me how, Im lost...
thank you so much..

Answer (score 3):

The process would be roughly the same as getting your BCH created at the fork. [Here's an answer I wrote on that](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/64691/can-i-sell-my-btc-and-still-claim-my-bch/64722#64722), but it's for a different wallet.

Let's review what happened:

1. You sent BTC to shapeshift from a Trezor wallet.
2. You wanted to trade for BCH.
3. Shapeshift asks for the receiving address.
4. You provided a BTC address instead of a BCH address.
5. Shapeshift sent BCH to an identical address generated with a BTC wallet.

Point 5 is where you might save yourself. BCH and BTC generate addresses identically. You sent Shapeshift an address that you generated, however, you generated it with your BTC wallet, instead of your BCH wallet. Since both coins generate addresses exactly the same way, you can use the private key for that BTC address and import/sweep it into your BCH wallet.

Do this:

1. Get the private key for the BTC address you generated to receive the BCH. I don't know how to use Trezor, so you'll have to get that info somewhere else; I'm sure it's not difficult.
2. Find the "import private keys" or "sweep wallet" feature for your BCH wallet software. You didn't say which software you use, but I'm sure it's also easy to find and use.
3. Take the private key from step 1 and input it into the import/sweep feature from step 2.
4. Enjoy the fact that you've successfully reclaimed your coin and be more careful next time. Confusing BTC for BCH has been a very common mistake since the fork.

Answer (score 2):

Just did the same blunder. Spent the better part of the day working around it.

In my case I sent bitcoin cash (BTH) from Coinbase to a mycelium wallet.

Here is how I recovered the funds.

First installed on my phone a wallet that supports BCH (mycelium is working on that, but even though I installed the mycelium bitcoin cash module app, no new app appeared and nothing changed in my existing mycelium app).

The wallet of choice was Coinomi.

Then I used the 12-word BIP39 mnemonic to restore the mycelium wallet into coinomi and also added Bitcoincash support (upper left corner, tap burger menu, bottom has `+COINS` where you add supported coins to see in your dashboard).

Afterwards, went on my PC (needed PC screen to scan a QR code with the coinomi app) to https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ and typed again my BIP39 mnemonic. Then scrolled down to `Derived addresses`. Looked up under column `Address` the BTC public address to which I had sent the BTH and ended up with this mess in the first place. Hovered mouse over `Private key` value corresponding to the BTC public address that received the funds. This showed up a QR code.

Back to coinomi, clicked the QR scan icon and in Ian Colmen's BIP39 page I scanned the QR of the private key mentioned above.

Happy ending.

[Link to github issue](https://github.com/mycelium-com/wallet-android/issues/459) for reference.