# Recovering a wallet from a lost device onto newly bought device

Tags: wallet-recovery

Please, in case my device get lost, broken, or abundoned, what can I do to recover my lost wallet address with my bitcoins onto my new device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the wallet "word seed" that is commonly used in popular wallets clients and what does it do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/45978/what-is-the-wallet-word-seed-that-is-commonly-used-in-popular-wallets-clients)

Comment: @chytrik I don't think that's a full answer; another reasonable direction for this question is to stress the importance of backups (which apply to software that doesn't have just a seed).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a wallet, based upon **hierarchical deterministic** (HD) standards (e.g. BIPs: 32/39/44/49), be sure you have already saved your BIP 39 seed words (typically 12, 18 or 24 words from a list of 2048 words that must be in saved in a specific order and spelled correctly) and any associated passphrase(s) in one or more secure locations. The passphrases are of your choosing and and can include special characters.

The BIP 39 seed words are needed to reconfigure your replacement software or hardware.  A BIP 39 passphrase provides and additional level of security if someone gains unauthorized visual access to your seed words. However, don't store your BIP 39 seed words and BIP 39 passphrases in the same location.

Not of aware of any software-based HD wallet GUIs that are supporting BIP 39 passphrases, seems to be mostly a feature the hardware vendors are supporting.

If you did not take these precautions in advance before your device was **lost/stolen/broken**, you are SOL.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: You can't get them

**Long answer**:
I would always use a backup in case something happens. 
However, If you use some kind of service as wallet they could possibly help you out. 
If you are like my, and don't want to trust a third-party with your keys, and keep them to yourself, you won't be able to recover them if your device gets destroyed or lost.

It's also important whether your "device" is your phone (not Galaxy S10 with built-in dedicated crypto wallet ;D) or a Ledger Nano/ Trezor, which seem pretty rugged to my. 
So, if we assume the device for whatever reason can't give your keys, you won't get them in a different way, unless prior to "the unfortunate event" you have made a backup.